# tabpanel width locked in rc2

Tags: rally, appsdk2

In rc2, the styling of the tabs of tabpanels has changed.  One big downside of this is that before the size of the tab itself was determined by the size of the title.  Now they are locked to a fixed size, and so the title can be truncated if it is too long.

Is there a way to override this behavior?  I've tried to set maxTabWidth to 'undefined', but that does not seem to help.

Here is an example of the new tabs:

[image]

And what they looked like previously:

[image]

Note that you can sort of get around this by setting minTabWidth to a high enough number, but then your tabs can take up a lot more space that they otherwise would, so this is not really practical for a window with a fair number of tabs.